# AP alterou pergunta com o texto de um comentário

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

É um pouco complicado de entender sem olhar.

Veja no link: [Re-escrever e fechar array de um arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83400/alterar-valor-inical-de-um-array)

Pelo que entendi, o AP editou a pergunta, substituindo ou adicionando no início o comentário integral do membro @Skywalker.

Fiquei em dúvida em reportar a um moderador pois acho que não precisa tomar tempo dos moderadores para algo tão pequeno.

Mas também fiquei em dúvida se poderia marcar para fechar como "amplo demais" ou "fora de escopo".

Apenas acho que o AP foi muito desleixado em apenas copiar o comentário ao invés de ele mesmo formular a pergunta.

Salvei screenshot para o caso da pergunta ser editada novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom, eu sugiro que você veja o tópico [*O problema dos Vampiros de ajuda*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/4808). Embora esse usuário não seja um vampiro (creio eu), lá tem algumas opções do que fazer em casos onde se recusam a tomar o tempo mínimo para escrever uma pergunta específica e coerente.

Comment: obrigado pelo link! parece um desses casos de vampirismo. Mas eu acho que foi ingenuidade do AP nesse caso específico.

Comment: marquei como pergunta como "não está clara o sufificente"

Comment: A edição pareceu equivocada, reverti para a pergunta original.

Comment: Postei o link na pergunta do autor, recomendo que sempre que possivel convide o autor da pergunta ou resposta que estiver debatendo pra participar :)

Comment: como convida alguém para participar de um debate no meta quando envolve o nome dessa pessoa? Tem alguma ferramenta prática para isso ou tem que mandar mensagem privada?

Comment: Nao, geralmente aqui debatemos abertamente, basta copiar o link no comentario da mesma maneira que eu fiz :)

Comment: A pergunta foi editada, acho que agora está clara o suficiente.

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade não é nem "amplo demais" nem "fora de escopo", ao meu ver você deveria marcar para fechar como "não está clara o suficiente", pois:

- **ampla demais**

  > Ocorre quando há muitas respostas possíveis ou boas respostas seriam muito longas para este formato.
- **Fora do escopo**

  > Ocorre a pergunta não esta no escopo do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, como por exemplo, perguntas em inglês e códigos que não podem ser reproduzidos.

---

O caso da dúvida discutida aqui é que não podemos entender a pergunta ou problema do autor e não com o código em si, então acredito que o correto seja realmente fechar como:

- **não está clara o suficiente**

  > Ocorre quando o autor não esclarece seu problema específico ou necessita de detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa, ou do modo escrito não é possível entender a dúvida.